# Display image while dragging

Tags: c#, wpf, image, drag-and-drop

How can i put an image in corner or center of cursor while user dragging an item in ListView or other controls like that?
When you dragging an image or text in Firefox; same thing occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most effective way I've found is to use the Adorner Layer.

This post shows how: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/marcelolr/showing-dragdrop-feedback-on-the-wpf-adorner-layer)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it's work on canvas. I want to use it on ListView.